# How to check if exception occured on disposing an event (.Net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, try-catch, dispose

On disposing an object I want to check if an exception is occured to choose wether I do a COMMIT or not. I am working with BAPIs against SAP.

If the creation of a transport order (1) fails, I want to cancel the material document (2). (But this is not of belong to the question)

```
          Dim rfcFunction As IRfcFunction

    Try

        Using sapConn3 As New SapConnectorV3
          ' (1) Creation of a Transport-Order
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

        Using sapConn3 As New SapConnectorV3
          ' (2) Cancel MaterialDocument
          ' (EDIT) The problem can be fixed if I call 
          ' "CommitTransaction" manually at this line. But I want to do 
          ' this automatically on disposing the object
        End Using

        Throw

    End Try
```

When the Using-Block ends the object gets disposed and at this moment I have to know if a exception occured.

This function is not working, because it states true on both disposings:

```
 Protected ReadOnly Property ExceptionOccurred() As Boolean
    Get
        Return Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetExceptionCode <> 0
    End Get
End Property
```

This is how I decide to do a Commit or not (part Dispose():

```
 Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose

     If Not ExceptionOccurred Then

        CommitTransaction()

    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tackle this from the opposite direction. Instead of trying to notify your `SapConnectionV3` object when a failure has occurred, tell it when you've *succeeded*.

You simply need to add a `Complete()` or `CompletedSuccessfully()` or similar method to your `SapConnectorV3`, which would set a private `bool` flag. Call it just before you leave the `Using` block. Then, inside your `Dispose` implementation, commit if the flag is true or rollback if it's false.

Then your calling convention becomes:

```
Using sapConn3 As New SapConnectorV3
    ' Do some work.
    sapConn3.Complete()
End Using ' Now this will commit if Complete was called, or roll back otherwise.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is what I Do in a similar way. I execute the commit directly. Seems that there is no real hint if I am within a try-section and that an exception occured, or?

Comment: @etalon11, this is simply not supported by the language. Exception information is not ambient. You could, in theory, let your `SapConnectorV3` actually *execute* the code inside the critical region by passing it in as an `Action` - then it can observe and re-throw any exceptions thrown by the delegate; but I wouldn't call that a pretty solution. In the .NET world it is more conventionally acceptable to do what I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your Try Catch and your using the wrong way round. I think the pattern you need is as follows:

```
Using sapConn3 As New SapConnectorV3
    Try   
      StartTransaction       
      ' (1) Creation of a Transport-Order
      CommitTransaction
    Catch ex As Exception
      ' (2) Cancel MaterialDocument
      RollbackTransaction
    End Try
End Using
```

Detecting that an exception occurred is simple, you put code in the `Catch` block to pick this up

"it is disposed because an exception is occured" - objects don't get disposed *because* an exception occurred so there is no way of detecting this inside the object itself. Consider these:

```
    Using sapConn3 As New SapConnectorV3
        Try
            'do something
        Catch ex As Exception
            'exception is thrown but object is not yet disposed
        End Try
    End Using 'object is now disposed


    Try
        Using sapConn3 As New SapConnectorV3
            'do somework
        End Using 'object is disposed here
    Catch ex As Exception
        'object must have be dispoed at this point as we are outide the using block
    End Try
```

So by using the first option you do not need to check inside the object itself

Comment: Sorry, this won't work for me. The material-document is already created and already committed. In SAP you cannot create a transport-order to a material-document which is not commited. So, please focus on "how to check if exception is occured". I know that this is a bit weird, but it is an SAP-interface with transaction-handling an not a relational database. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: The answer to the question "how do i check if an exception occurred" is that code enters the catch block. You may not be able to rollback the transaction, but you can still reverse whatever you did.

Comment: I edited my code to show you the workaround I am using. But don't hang up on the commiting or rollbacking. I just want to know how I can check on disposing a object if it is disposed because an exception is occured.

Comment: Objects don't necesarily get disposed because of an exception occurred, but in your code, the object will be disposed at the point that code in your catch block runs, that is why you need to change the order of your using and try blocks